# Basic Jquery Question - hiding an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

sorry for this question but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to hide the "#postcodeConf" element on page load but it just doesn't do it! I put the code in JSfiddle and it works as expected!

What am I doing wrong?!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>
$("#postcodeConf").hide();
</script>

</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="postcodeEntry">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
        <p id="postcodeConf">Postcode Ok</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that `$("#postcodeConf").hide();` runs before the element is created in the html. Wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <input type="text" id="postcodeEntry">
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
     <p id="postcodeConf">Postcode Ok</p>  

    <script>
     $("#postcodeConf").hide();
    </script>
```

Add in the following order as dom element can be captured only after its rendered.